# How can we avoid staff users overwriting emails of utility WordPress accounts when testing CiviContribute pages?

Tags: wordpress, cms-integration

I installed the latest CiviCRM on WordPress. WordPress is set up to refuse new accounts to the public, and there are about 12 utility admin/editor related accounts not tied to a specific person: AdminCrm, Editor, Staff1, Staff2, etc.

There is an ongoing problem if the logged-in user uses or tests a contribution page, because CiviCRM mixes up the current WordPress login with the user's contact information. The person logged into WordPress is invariably a member of the organization, and if they renew their membership while logged into one of these utility accounts, the email address for the renewal is copied from that of the *current* login which results in a duplicate contact created.

It would be nice if there was some way to turn off this behavior. I think CiviCRM on Wordpress was designed to assume contacts were always linked to a Wordpress login. Need suggestions on how to handle this day-to-day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should also consider giving your staff their own personal user accounts for a number of reasons.

- It will be clear that they're acting as themselves rather than as a generic staff person
- You can isolate the culprit(s) who are recording memberships the wrong way (see Jon's answer), meaning they don't cause problems for others and you can talk with them specifically
- When people leave the organization, change roles, etc. you don't need to change the password for everyone

Comment: I never thought of this. I think we will move in this direction.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally, the day-to-day workflow of entering contributions/memberships for your staff should be to use the back-end forms, not the front-end forms, so you don't experience this.  However, to help with this transition, you may want to consider installing the "no overwrite" extension, which prevents the problem you're describing: https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite