# Administrator contact record duplicated when do Activity Send Email

Tags: contacts, activities, duplicate-contacts, administer

One administrator's contact record is duplicated every time she performs the Activity action "Send email".  The recipient's activity record indicates it was "added by" and points to a new contact record with the first, last and email of the administrator (no WP account associated with it).  (There are now a very large number of these duplicate records!!)

Note, when she sends bulk emails, that activity is recorded under her correct logged in contact (associated with her WP account).

We thought it might be because there was a "From email addresses" associated with her name/email, but disabling it didn't help.  (Can't be deleted without removing linked activity records which is not desirable).  And another administrator with a From email does not duplicate.

I tried logging in as her and it still does it, so it is not the sequence of actions just she is performing.  When I and other administrators send emails from our admin accounts, there is no duplication.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: This is recent behavior although there were some WP configuration changes the month earlier.  Just noticed this possibly related thread:  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/197/wordpress-duplicates-my-contacts?rq=1

Comment: Is it immediate, or is there a delay of a few minutes between the send email and the duplicate creation? (Should be visible from the activity vs contact timestamps.)

Comment: @chris The contact is created immediately; the timestamps show it created one second before the activity is inserted. This install is running Civi 4.6.26 and WP 4.7.4 - Thanks!

Comment: @chris WOW!! Looking at those creation dates and drilling down showed that multiple identical contacts were created for just that one Send Email.  I logged in as that administrator and just logging in created 7 new contacts!!!

Comment: I'd guess that some integration to link contacts with WordPress users is misbehaving. Debugging the software in depth may be called for here, I'm not sure we'll solve it by question and answer! But if you do find a switch somewhere that fixes it, please say so on this question :)

Comment: That related question does look like a match. Andrew's solution there is likely to solve it this time, but an even better outcome would be understanding what the specific problem is and correcting that in civicrm so you and other sites don't hit it again! Is there a chance you or someone can debug this in greater depth?

Comment: @chris I believe I need to resync my WP users with my Civi contacts but am concerned about all the contacts with the same email.

My understanding is that if existing links exist in the civicrm_uf_match table (whether they be right or wrong :/), they work on the Civi ID in the uf_match table.  But if I empty _uf_match table then the sync will be matched on email in the wp_users table; what if there are multiple contacts with the WP email in the Civi DB (my problem) - will it link on lowest Internal Civi ID?

Thanks for your help!